# Probability of shortened sequence of coin tosses

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

A coin is tossed 9 times, and the outcomes are marked with the letters H (meaning Heads) and T (Tails). It can't land on the edge.

That sequence of 9 letters is shortened by crossing out all the H's before the first T and all the H's after the last T (if any).

For example, HHTTHTTTH would be shortened to TTHTTT.

1. What is the probability that the shortened sequence will have exactly 5 letters?
2. What is the most likely length of the shortened sequence?

*My thoughts:*

Since the coin is tossed 9 times and there are 2 different outcomes, the number of possible outcomes is 2⁹ = 512.

The coin will have 5 letters if:

a) There's a T in the 5th position of the sequence, HHHHT####. However, there shouldn't be other T's followed by H's. HHHHTTTTT would be fine, while HHHHTTTTH wouldn't.

So, the first 4 symbols must be H and followed by a T. Then, 3 symbols can be either T or H. Assuming that the very last symbol is T, there are 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 1 = 6 different combinations. However, if the last symbol isn't T, then the only suitable sequence is HHHHTHHHH, so, I can say that there are 7 ways so far.

b) There's a T in 1st-4th position, and the last letter of the shortened sequence is T, for example, T####THHH.

The first symbol is T, followed by 4 symbols that are either T or H. That is followed by a T, ending with 3 H's. The first T can be in 4 different positions. So there are 4 * (1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1) = 64 different combinations.

Combining both a) and b), there are 7 + 64 = 71 different combinations in total. So, the probability should be 71 / 512 = ~0.1387.

I know that my solution is rather manual and it would be hard to answer the second question doing everything manually. My logic may have also missed some possible combinations. Is there a simpler way to think about this problem?

Comment: For 2nd question, We can consider only the 1st rule : All leading H are canceled.  Probability to cancel the 1st letter is 1/2 ; probability to cancel the 2nd letter is 1/4, etc. We have a geometric suit, Average number deleted on the left side of the sequence : $1/2 + 1/4 +$ ... $+ 1/2^9= 1-1/2^{10}$ ; same for right side of the sequence. But we count twice the specific case HHHHHHHHH.

Comment: How does that help me?

Comment: See the Addendum that I have just added to my answer.  My mistake for initially overlooking your second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give an alternate approach to the 1st question.  For the 2nd question, see the Addendum at the end of my answer.

Let $A$ denote the event that there are $a$ **leading** Heads (on the LHS of the sequence).

Let $B$ denote the event that there are $b$ **trailing** Heads (on the RHS of the sequence).

The shortened sequence will have $5$ letters if and only if $(a + b) = 4.$

Then, since the sequence is $9$ characters long, whenever $(a + b) = 4,$ then you have that events A and B are independent of each other.

So, $\displaystyle p(A) = \frac{1}{2^{a+1}}, ~p(B) = \frac{1}{2^{b+1}}$.

Therefore, the probability that $(a + b) = 4$ is

$$\sum_{i=0}^4 \frac{1}{2^{i+1}} \times \frac{1}{2^{[4-i]+1}} = \sum_{i=0}^4 \frac{1}{2^i \times 2^{-i} \times 2^6}$$

$$= \frac{5}{64} = \frac{40}{512}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{where you made your mistake}}$

Your analysis under *b)* discussed having a T in the 1st - 4th position.  It should have been having the **first** T in the 1st-4th position.

So, the number of ways of having (for example)

HHHT---H is $2^3 = 8.$

Another way of thinking about this is that (from my previous analysis), there are $5$ **fixed** leading/trailing sequences.

For each such sequence there is always exactly $3$ **unconstrained positions**, which are between the 1st and last T, wherever these are positioned.

This intuitively explains the alternate approach of

$$\frac{5 \times 2^3}{512}.$$

---

**Addendum**
The most likely length of the shortened sequence is **either** $9$ or $8$.

A shortened sequence of length $9$ will occur if and only if the first and last elements of the  sequence are both Tails.  This means that there are $7$ unconstrained elements, so the probability of this happening is

$$\frac{1}{4} = \frac{2^7}{2^9} = \frac{128}{512}.$$

For comparison purposes, simply associate the number $128 = 2^7$, with the shortened sequence of length $9$.

For a shortened sequence of length $8$, you either have HT------T or T------TH.  Each of the two possibilities has $6$ unconstrained positions, so the number of occurrences for a shortened sequence of length $8$ is

$$2 \times 2^6 = 2 \times 64 = 128.$$

---

The pattern is now clear.  For the shortened sequence of length $7$, there are $3$ separate leading/trailing possibilities, each of which leaves $5$ unconstrained positions.

$$3 \times 2^5 < 128.$$

So, the shortened sequences of lengths $8$ or $9$ are equally likely, and each is more probable then any of the other lengths.

Comment: The solution is great - thanks for the help! However, just want to add something - a scenario to consider would be HHHHHHHHH when it comes to the 2nd question, so probably it makes the length of 9 more likely to occur, correct?

Comment: @elephanty Unclear, and depends on how you interpret the phrase : "That sequence of 9 letters is shortened by crossing out all the H's before the first T and all the H's after the last T (if any)."  The *if any* clause is clearly intended to refer specifically to the fact that there might not be any H's after the last T.  However, it could also be interpreted as referring to the last T (i.e. there may not be a last T).  ...see next comment

Comment: @elephanty Under the 2nd (arguably less likely) interpretation, any *trailing* H's are eliminated, regardless of whether a *last T* exists or not.  Getting past that, and assuming the more likely interpretation of the phrase *if any*, you have the 2nd issue: if there are no T's at all, then it could be argued that all of the H's are **before** the first (non-existent) T.  Frankly, I speculate (perhaps wrongly) that this is the problem composer's intent.   ...see next comment

Comment: @elephanty That is, my speculation is that the problem composer intended HHHHHHHHH to be shortened to a length of $0$.  The reason is that problem composers typically intend to test Math students on Mathematical concepts, rather than weird interpretations of (arguably ambiguous) semantics.